# When is an increasing union a colimit?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, limits-and-colimits

Let's consider a diagram $\Phi: \lambda \to \mathcal{T}_*$
$$
X_0 \to X_1 \to \cdots \to X_\xi \to X_{\xi+1} \to \cdots
$$
of pointed spaces,
indexed by some ordinal $\lambda$, in which each $X_\xi$ is a
subspace of a certain space $Y$ and each map $X_\zeta\to X_\xi$ is
the inclusion map.

I have the idea that 'morally' the categorical colimit of the diagram is simply the union $X = \bigcup_{\xi< \lambda} X_\xi$ (with the subspace topology).  Certainly this is not actually the case in general -- we need some topological restrictions.

I'm willing to impose *really strong* topological restrictions.
First of all, I'm happy to assume
all of the maps $X_\zeta \to X_{\xi}$ and   $X_\xi \to Y$
are cofibrations.  I'd even be pretty happy to have an argument in which each map $X_\xi \to X_{\xi + 1}$ is obtained by attaching a cell, or a cone.
Furthermore, I'm content to work with a category of spaces (such as CGWH) for which cofibrations
are necessarily inclusions of closed subspaces (up to homeomorphism).

In general, of course, there is a comparison map $c: \mathrm{colim}\ \Phi\to X$, and it is
clearly surjective.  It would suffice, therefore, to prove that $c$ is a cofibration.

Unfortunately, my diagram-wrangling skills are coming up short.  I'd appreciate pointers to a good argument or a useful reference.

Comment: Isn't that always the case as soon as the union is equiped with the initial topology ? If the problem is that you don't want to use the initial topology, what topology do you put on the union ?

Comment: The union gets the subspace topology.

Comment: how about section 3.2 here: http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf ?

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work, I'm too busy right now to think about it. Take $X=\mathbb{N}$ and give it the cofinite topology. Let $X_n=\{1,\dots,n\}$ for each $n\geq1$. Then $X_n$ is discrete, and $X_{n+1}$ is obtained from $X_n$ by attaching a $0$-cell. Each $X_n\subseteq X$ is closed, and I think it it a cofibration (it has a halo in $X$?). As sets $X=\bigcup X_n$, but as spaces $colim\;X_n$ is discrete. Note that everything is compactly generated (although not weak Hausdorff?).

Comment: Let $X_n=\{1, 1/2, \ldots, 1/n, 0\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. When we take the colimit, we just get a countable set with the discrete topology, which is different from the subspace topology of the union of the $X_n$'s in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It looks like Matt's example shows that there is no interesting set of restrictions that work!

Comment: Conversely, I think Lemma 3.7 in Strickland's notes may do the job for me.  I'm checking details before suggesting Dylan Wilson upgrade to an answer, though.

Comment: @MattFeller I see your point, but I don't think these inclusions can be thought of as cone attachments.

Comment: ah, I missed the thing about some ambient space we were taking the subspace topology in... I'm inclined to agree with Matt/Nick. Surely an inclusion between finite sets is a cofibration (you are attaching a cone on the empty set.)

Comment: @DylanWilson Not in the category of pointed spaces!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got the proof I need.  Strickland's Lemma 3.7 requires a compactness condition:  for every compact $C$ in $Y$, $C\cap X = C\cap X_\xi$ for some $\xi$.  I can prove this condition when each $X_\xi \to X_{\xi+1}$ is obtained by a a cone attachment.  I'll post details when I've got them written up.